# Spring Security Intermittent remember-me failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, remember-me

We use Spring Security 3.1.3 to manage the login sessions for iCrumz.com. We are experiencing an intermittent failure of Spring Security's 'remember me' feature. Users are required to login often (ranging from just about every use to every few days) instead of 2 weeks since last visit (Spring Security default).

The failure seems to be independent of browser or operating system. It has been randomly observed on our Development, Staging and Production servers. The duration of remembered login and the user activity immediately prior to the failure appear to be random.

I have captured aggregated log snippets that demonstrate successful and unsuccessful remembered logins.

The problem seems to begin with Tomcat (apparently) returning a status 500, which shows up in the nginx log. 
What strikes me as odd is that the first sign of trouble in the Tomcat log (catalina.out) is the "No HttpSession currently exists" entry, which does not appear for over .6 seconds after the 500 reported by nginx. That leads me to wonder if the timestamps are not truly coordinated, even though nginx and Tomcat are running on the same Linux machine. I have confirmed the log time vs clock time is accurate, by comparing known real world events like logging in, with the logs.

All URLs are configured (in nginx) to use HTTPS site-wide, but the connection between nginx and Tomcat is http (not https). I don't see why that would be a problem, but I read somewhere in the last few days that it might be, so I'm mentioning it in case it matters.

Any troubleshooting pointers, assistance, comments, etc., would be most appreciated.

6/10/14 - As noted in the comments, this problem was found to be a symptom of a loss of session, which is not a 'remember me' problem.

RememberMe-success.txt (sorted latest entry on top)

```
5/29/14
6:31:11.809 AM
2014-05-29 06:31:11,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
6:31:11.809 AM
2014-05-29 06:31:11,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@c9dc36eb: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@c9dc36eb: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@329d9783: Username: [PROTECTED]; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
6:31:11.809 AM
2014-05-29 06:31:11,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
6:31:11.503 AM
2014-05-29 06:31:11,503 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.icrumz.icrumz.web.IcrumzController - populateCollection: 4 Columns, 23 Folders, 108 Bookmarks
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
6:31:11.000 AM
23.242.113.153 - - [29/May/2014:06:31:11 -0700] "GET /icrumz.html HTTP/1.1" 200 13453 "https://icrumz.com/login.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
sourcetype = access-nginx
```

RememberMe-failure.txt (sorted latest entry on top)

```
5/29/14
11:31:05.704 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,704 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.704 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,704 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.704 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,704 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie detected
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.654 AM
2014-05-29 11:31:05,654 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /icrumz.html at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
sourcetype = application-tomcat
5/29/14
11:31:05.000 AM
99.50.193.130 - - [29/May/2014:11:31:05 -0700] "GET /icrumz.html HTTP/1.1" 500 2246 "https://icrumz.com/login.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/35.0.1916.38 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
sourcetype = access-nginx
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <!-- Disable AOP generated login processing url so LoginController can respond -->
        <form-login 
            login-processing-url="" 
            login-page="#{@icrumzConfigService.getHostURL()}login.html" 
            username-parameter="email" 
            password-parameter="pswd" />

        <logout
            logout-url="/logout"
            logout-success-url="#{@icrumzConfigService.getHostURL()}login.html"
            invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login.html"/>
        <http-basic/>
        <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" key="[A_GUID]"/>

        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/icrumz*/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/change-password*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />        
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/auth_check" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> <!-- requires-channel="https"/ -->
    </http>

    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- DAO Based Security -->
        <authentication-provider>

            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>

            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT U.username AS username, U.password as password, U.enabled as enabled FROM icrumz_user U where U.username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT U.username as username, A.role_name as authority FROM icrumz_user U left join icrumz_user_roles UA on U.id=UA.icrumz_user left join icrumz_role A on UA.roles = A.id WHERE U.username=?" 
            />

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: How big is the data source storing ```remember-me``` cookies? Is it possible that you displace or overwrite existing records in the data source, making random cookies invalid? If you have a process that occasionally cleans the database, is there any way for it to corrupt or delete cookies that are still alive? Just some ideas.

Comment: @Misha I'm using the JDBC persistent_logins, managed by Spring Security,  as configured by Spring Roo. -- 

There are 340 users, 400 persistent_logins, with 149 users represented. Some users have a single persistent_logins record, some a few, some 30 or more. -- 

A single user with three or four devices might have as many records, but 10, 20, 30 or more seems odd. -- 

149 persistent_logins users seems OK. Due to inactive users or no persistent login set. -- 

Does 30 or more persistent_logins suggest a problem? Do you have any ideas on further investigation?

Comment: Just found [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html)  PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices  `Note that while this class will ..., it will not delete these tokens from storage. A suitable batch process should be run periodically to remove expired tokens from the database.`  Guess that's why 30+ records for some users.

Comment: Yes, it suggests a problem :) Try cleaning expired tokens periodically and see if the problems persist, I guess.

Comment: After upgrading Spring and Spring security to latest versions, tuning Spring Security configuration to avoid authorization attempts on non-secure resources, etc., The problem has been isolated to a basic session failure, not the Remember Me feature. After the update, the session failure can be seen in the logs, even when Remember Me is not selected at login.

Comment: The session failure noted above was just the normal session timeout. I'm still dealing with the fallout from updating the Spring projects, but the problem seems to remain. The session expiration was expected in the absents of Remember Me. Still investigating